# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'runTest'

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm am new to `unittest` and I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
runTest (__main__.TestTimeInterval)
No test ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Trinity/qa-trinity/python_lib/qe/tests/test_timestamp_interval.py", line 122, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Trinity/qa-trinity/python_lib/qe/tests/test_timestamp_interval.py", line 110, in main
    result_set = runner.run(suite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/runner.py", line 168, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/suite.py", line 87, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/suite.py", line 125, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 625, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 555, in run
    testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
AttributeError: 'TestTimeInterval' object has no attribute 'runTest'
```

I wanted to create a simple test to see if everything is working properly but I got the error above. I added the test to the suite and then ran it with `.run()`

```
class TestTimeInterval(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, log, runtag, interval, path_file):
        super(TestTimeInterval, self).__init__()
        self.interval = interval
        self.path_file = path_file
        self.log = log
        self.runtag = runtag

    def test_record(self):
        self.assertTrue(1 > 0)


##############################################################################
def main(argv):
    exit_code = 0
    global me; me = os.path.basename(argv[0]) # name of this program
    global mydir; mydir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=main.__doc__)
    parser.add_argument("file", metavar="FILE",
                        help="File filled with hdfs paths separated by newlines")
    parser.add_argument("runtag", metavar="RUNTAG", help="tag for the test run")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--time", default="10", dest="interval",
                        help="Time interval (minutes) between server_timestamp and interval given by HDFS folder name")
    args = parser.parse_args(args=argv[1:])
    log = logging.getLogger(me)
    logfile = args.runtag + ".log"
    if os.path.exists(logfile):
        os.remove(logfile)
    log.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(logfile))
    console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr); console.setLevel(logging.WARNING); log.addHandler(console)
    if exit_code == 0:
        runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=sys.stdout, descriptions=True, verbosity=2)
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        print(args)
        suite.addTest(TestTimeInterval(log, args.runtag, args.interval, args.file))
        try:
            log.info("{0}: START: {1}".format(me, datetime.datetime.now().ctime()))
            result_set = runner.run(suite)
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            log.info("{0}: exit on keyboard interrupt".format(me))
            exit_code = 1
        else:
            exit_code = len(result_set.errors) + len(result_set.failures)
        finally:
            log.info("{0}: FINISH: {1}".format(me, datetime.datetime.now().ctime()))
    return exit_code
##############################################################################
# The following code calls main only if this program is invoked standalone
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm going into the right direction here, but why are you overriding `__init__()`, rather than implementing `setUp()`?

Comment: @favoretti i need to pass in arguments so I thought I could initialize the object with the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You almost never need to create TestSuites and TestRunners yourself.  Normally, you'd do something like:

```
# my_test.py
import unittest

class Something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestSomething, self).setUp()
        self.something = Something()

    def test_record(self):
        self.assertTrue(1 > 0)

    def test_something_foo_equals_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.something.foo, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

now, to run your test, you just execute your script.

```
python my_test.py
```

Comment: How do I pass in an object into `TestSomething` to be tested against?

Comment: @Liondancer -- Generally, `TestSomething` should _create_ objects to test.  A few special methods (`setUp` and `tearDown`) run before and after each test so that is a natural place to create objects that need to be tested.  I'll update my example code...

Comment: I'm still a little confused because in my code, I create an object (`Something`) with my positional arguments. Wouldn't I need to pass something into `TestSomething` in order to use the object I just create?

Comment: @Liondancer -- Not sure I understand.  In your test, you can create `Something` using whatever positional arguments you want to pass to it ...

Comment: http://dpaste.com/35ZFJ6J If you look on line 70, I created an object. But I'm not sure how I can pass that instance to be used in the `setUp`.